# Is there a way to get the key name in value of JSON file

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, json.net

I want to populate a property based on the name of the name of the key.  E.g. The AddressType for the physicalAddress would be physicalAddress.  Currently Im using Newtonsoft.Json.  This information will be stored in a database using EntityFramework.

Thanks

This is an example part of the JSON file:

```
"person": [
  {
    "physicalAddress": [
      {
        "address": "123 Street Name",
        "postCode": 1122
      }
    ],
    "postalAddress": [
      {
        "address": "123 Street Name",
        "postCode": 1122
      }
    ],
    "registeredAddress": [
      {
        "address": "123 Street Name",
        "postCode": 1122
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is an example part of the class:

```
    [JsonProperty("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("postCode")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    public string AddressType { get; set; }
```

Comment: You would need custom serialization code (e.g. a `JsonConverter`)

Comment: Perhaps create a `PhysicalAddress` class that has a readonly property of `AddressType` (and same for `postalAddress` etc)? _Each of those classes could inherit from an abstract class with an abstract readonly `AddressType` property._

Comment: physicalAddress in your JSON is really intended as an Array or as an Object? Because in your example it is like an array. But I ask this question so that I we can determine the right thing to do on your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want or can't change the client side, one possible approach is to create a request model that matches the format of the request body, i.e.

```cs
  [JsonProperty("physicalAddress")]
  public List<AddressRequestModel> PhysicalAddress { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("postalAddress")]
  public List<AddressRequestModel> PostalAddress{ get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("registeredAddress")]
  public List<AddressRequestModel> RegisteredAddress{ get; set; }
```

Where `AddressRequestModel` would be the class containing the properties `Address` and `PostCode`. Then when the request is received, map the request model to the model needed by your application. In the mapper you can assign the appropriate address type, i.e.

```cs
public class AddressMapper
{
   public List<AddressRequestModel> Map(RequestModel model)
   {
      var addresses = new List<AddressRequestModel>();
      model.PhysicalAddress.ForEach(address => addresses.Add(Map(address, "physicalAddress"));
      model.PostalAddress.ForEach(address => addresses.Add(Map(address, "postalAddress"));
      model.RegisteredAddress.ForEach(address => addresses.Add(Map(address, "registeredAddress"));
      return addresses;
   }

   private AddressRequestModel Map(AddressRequestModel model, string addressType) =>
   new AddressRequestModel
   {
       Address = model.Address,
       PostCode = model.PostCode,
       AddressType = addressType,
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a bit complex case to parse this json by JsonConverter. And it works for your requirements.

The major function uses `JProperty` to dynamic get the address key name (physicalAddress, postalAddress, or other) and `Children()` to get sub nodes.

```cs
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         string json = @"
{""person"": [
  {
    ""physicalAddress"": [
      {
        ""address"": ""123 Street Name"",
        ""postCode"": 1122
      },
      {
        ""address"": ""456 Street Name"",
        ""postCode"": 7788
      }
    ],
    ""postalAddress"": [
      {
        ""address"": ""123 Street Name"",
        ""postCode"": 1122
      },
      {
        ""address"": ""9999 Street Name"",
        ""postCode"": 77886666
      }
    ],
    ""registeredAddress"": [
      {
        ""address"": ""123 Street Name"",
        ""postCode"": 1122
      },
      {
        ""address"": ""fwerg Street Name"",
        ""postCode"": 9999999
      }

    ]
  }
  
  ]
}
";

         Person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json, new MyTypeConverter());
     }
}

public class Person
{
    public List<AddressDetail> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class AddressDetail
{
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    public string AddressType { get; set; }
}

public class MyTypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Person).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(objectType.GetTypeInfo());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);
            if (item["person"] != null)
            {
                var pseron = new Person()
                {
                    Addresses = new List<AddressDetail>()
                };
                var largeAddressArr = item["person"].Children();
                foreach (var largeAddress in largeAddressArr)
                {
                    foreach (var keyAddress in largeAddress.Children())
                    {
                        string keyName = (keyAddress as JProperty).Name;
                        List<JToken> tokens = keyAddress.Children().ToList();
                        foreach (var address in tokens)
                        {
                            var addresses = address.ToObject<List<AddressDetail>>();
                            addresses.ForEach(x => x.AddressType = keyName);
                            pseron.Addresses.AddRange(addresses);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return pseron;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```